# for s in string_list: s = func(s) can't change string s

Tags: python

```
def func(s):
    s = s + " is corrected"
    return s

string_list = ["She", "He"]

for s in string_list:
    s = func(s)
```

After this, string_list is not modifyed but,

```
for i in range( len(string_list) ):
    string_list[i] = func(string_list[i])
```

This works, why this happen?

Comment: The later is changing the element of `list` with _new_ string. `str` is immutable whereas `list` is mutable.

Comment: In Python, _no_ variables act as a “proxy” reference. That is, assignment to a variable is always separate from what the variable previously named / evaluated to, regardless of how the variable is introduced.

Comment: exactly what @user2864740 said, in the first example you are chaging s, not an element of string_list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Your code

```py
string_list[i] = func(string_list[i])
```

does not change the value stored at `string_list[i]`, it assigns a NEW value to `string_list[i]`.

Similarly the code

```py
s = func(s)
```

does not change the value of `s`, it creates a new value and assigns it to `s`.

---

Contrast this with actual mutations, where your function does *change* the value it's operating on (rather than creating a new one). `list.append` applies mutation to the list, so something like:

```py
list_of_lists = [[1], [2], [3]]

for lst in list_of_lists:
    lst.append('new')
```

Will actually change `list_of_lists`. This is because you're pulling the value (`[1]`, `[2]`, and `[3]`, respectively) out and making a change to it.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `s` first refers to the string in the list.  When you reassign it to `func(s)`, you're causing the **variable** `s` to refer to a different object.  The original object (that is, the one in the list) is unchanged.  The only change is to which **object** the variable `s` refers.

In the second example, the command `string_list[i] = ...` invokes `string_list`'s `__setitem__` method which does change which objects are contained in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not overwriting the list, here is how to fix it *(with a list comprehension)*:

```
def func(s):
    s = s + " is corrected"
    return s

string_list = ["She", "He"]


string_list = [func(s) for s in string_list]
print(string_list)
```

Output:

```
['She is corrected', 'He is corrected']
```